# What is wrong with this Dictionary initializer

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I may have gone completely blind, but I can't see anything wrong with this code:

```
public static Dictionary<States, string> NameMap = new Dictionary<States, string>
{
    [States.State1] = "State1",
    [States.State2] = "State2",
    [States.State3] = "State3",
    [States.State4] = "State4",
    [States.State5] = "State5",
    [States.State6] = "State6"
};
```

When attempting to build I get a tone of these errors:

```
Invalid expression term '['
```

(This points at the first Bracket on each line)

and

```
Syntax error, ',' expected
```

This points at the * columns:

```
[States*.State1]* = "State1",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Plopping these values in via .Add works fine.

States is an Enum btw.

Comment: Maybe this is in some CSHTML or ASPX file?

Comment: are you sure you're using C# 6?

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to compile this with an older C# compiler.

Comment: I tried your code myself, it compiles without any trouble. Check your csproj and your target framework.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, maybe this is some dumb issue with Resharper changing to C#6, but I'm actually in the previous version.

Comment: Make sure you are using MSBUILD located in Program Files (x86).

Comment: @Glitcher Let me guess: you typed in an old-style initializer, and then ReSharper suggested to refactor? This is how I learned about this new syntax :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Exactly. Damn thing just cost me 30 minutes.

Comment: Does no one read the trades anymore...sheesh :)

Comment: FYI, c# 6 features are compile features. It was suggested to check the target framework but what really needs to be checked is which compiler is being used. In this case, roslyn would need to be used.

Comment: @Glitcher 30 minutes in exchange for learning something new and cool sounds like a fair trade to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was caused by Resharper simply assuming I was using the C# 6 compiler and 'correcting' my code accordingly. Upon examination, I'm not using C# 6, and Resharper is lucky I haven't deleted it

Comment: You can give hint to Resharper about version of C# by indicating "C# Language Level" in project's properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Your Syntax is right!**

You can test it here: http://www.volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=69450

This called **Index initializers**

> Object and collection initializers are useful for declaratively
>   initializing fields and properties of objects, or giving a collection
>   an initial set of elements. Initializing dictionaries and other
>   objects with indexers is less elegant. We are adding a new syntax to
>   object initializers allowing you to set values to keys through any
>   indexer that the new object has

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    [7] = "seven",
    [9] = "nine",
    [13] = "thirteen"
};
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6